# Query withColumn Pyspark to add a column dataframe based on array

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

```
   "people"      "other"
   father         ...
   mother
   cat
   brother
   dog
```

I'm going to insert new column, if column `people` contains word in specific array then modify the content with that of other array, else word will remain the same:

```
array=['father','mother','brother']
array_new=['dad','mum','bro']

   "people"      "other"     "new"
   father         ...        dad
   mother                    mum
   cat                       cat
   brother                   bro
   dog                       dog
```

I think to use this:

```
expression = ("CASE " +"".join(["WHEN people LIKE '{}' THEN '{}' ".format(val,array_new[array.index(val)](val)) for val in array]) +"ELSE 'None' END")

df_pyspark = df_pyspark.withColumn("new", functions.expr(expression))
```

I should change the `else` condition, but I don't know how to do it, for copy the same word in the else condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a literal map expression that you create from `array` and `array_new` using `create_map` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import chain

mapping = F.create_map(*[F.lit(x) for x in chain(*zip(array, array_new))])

df1 = df.withColumn("new", F.coalesce(mapping[F.col("people")], F.col("people")))
```

---

Or using `na.replace` by passing a dict that you create from the two arrays like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

mapping_dict = dict(zip(array, array_new))

df1 = df.withColumn("new", F.col("people")).na.replace(mapping_dict, subset=["new"])
```

---

Another way by chaining multiple `when` expressions:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

when_expr = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc.when(F.col("people") == x[0], x[1]),
    zip(array, array_new),
    F
).otherwise(F.col("people"))

df1 = df.withColumn("new", when_expr)
```

Comment: It work corectly, thanks!